# Prove that the set of square matrices $A(x)=\begin{pmatrix} 2x+y & x \\ 3x & 2x+3y \\ \end{pmatrix}$ for $x,y\in [0,1]$ is a compact set.

Tags: calculus, analysis, continuity, compactness

Prove that the set of square matrices $A(x)=\begin{pmatrix} 2x+y & x \\ 3x & 2x+3y \\ \end{pmatrix}$ for $x,y\in [0,1]$ is a compact set.(Take into consideration metric $d_2...$)

I was thinking to show that this is a linear image between normed spaces, but am not sure how to do that because of $x$ and $y$ thereby showing that it is a continuous function. And everyone knows that the continuous map of a compact set is compact. Could it be that $A(x)$ is accually $A(x,y)$? Its very clear on my page that its $A(x).$

Comment: a matrix function is continuous if each component is continuous

Comment: I need proof of that. :D

Comment: Ultimately it comes down to the fact that all norms on finite dimensional spaces induce the product topology (in particular, they are equivalent).

Comment: @RogerFederer the space of matrices is finite dimensional. don't you have some theorem that says every pair of norms on a finite dimensional space is equivalent?

Comment: I honestly do not have these theorems.

Comment: $|e_i^T (A(x,y)-A(x^*, y^*)) e_j| \le \|A(x,y)-A(x^*, y^*)\| \|e_i\| \|e_j\| to 0$ for $(x,y)\to (x^*, y^*)$ implies that each components of $A$ is continuous

Comment: as for the question, yes continuous image of a compact set is compact again.

Comment: Consider the set $A :=\{{(2x+y,x,3y,2x+3y):x,y\in [0,1]}\}\subset \mathbb{R}^4$. It is enough to show that $A$ is closed and bounded, i think you can proceed.

Answer (score 1):

The map $x \mapsto A(x)$ is continuous.  The interval $[0,1]$ is compact.  You are now done.  Note that all norms on a finite dimensional space are equivalent.

Comment: I still do not know why $A(x)$ is continuous. Dont know how to prove this.

Comment: All four components are continuous, therefore the map itself is continuous.